# Objects in array display as [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm trying to save an `array` which includes a `object` to a `hidden field` in a `form`. When I do so, the `object` doesn't show up, but is display like "[object Object]" instead.

```
arrayObject = [
    "something",
    { objectKey: "something else", otherObjectKey: "totally different" },
    "quite similar"
];

$("input").val(arrayObject);
```

**This outputs**

> "something,[object Object],quite similar"

What can I do different?

Comment: Do you know what objects are and how they work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it into the hidden field after serializing it as JSON like this:

```
$("input").val(JSON.stringify(arrayObject));
```

And parse it into the arrayObject while reading it back like this:

```
var savedArray = JSON.parse($("input").val());
```

Comment: Worth noting that [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) is required to ensure that `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` work in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, json2.js will be required in older versions of browsers. Newer versions have these JSON methods built-in. Forgot to point that out! :)

Comment: @jakeclarkson: Which browers are you refering to? I tried it in IE7, 8, 9, Opera 11, Firefox 8, Safari 5.1.2 and Chrome 15 and it worked in all of those.

Comment: As you've correctly pointed out all modern browsers will have native support for the `JSON` `Object`. In terms of browsers that don't support it: IE6 is the one that springs to mind; if anyone is unfortunate enough to be using this still :-). By including the file you have peace of mind that `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` are always available.

Comment: I'm not optimizing for ie6 no longer, so that's fine by me... Thanks for the concern though.

Comment: Including json2.js is a precautionary step more than anything. One downside though is I believe the JSON definition in json2.js will overwrite the native definition and potentially cause a slight degradation in performance..

Comment: Not if you define the JS within a `IF lte IE6`-tag?

Comment: @KennethB - Yes, that is right. Wondering how i didn't think of that! :-)

Answer (score -1):

$("input").val(JSON.stringify(arrayObject))